# Как вызвать функцию передавая ей не все параметры?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть функция которая принимает максимум 4 параметра. При этом в разных слуаях я буду вызывать ее и передавать только 3, 2, или 1 параметр. Unity выдает ошибку что еслипараметр задан в ункции то он должен быть передан обязательно. Есть ли способ указать параметры как опциональные, или лучше использовать другое решение (какое)?

Пример:

```
void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2, Texture texture3, Texture texture4) {

  renderer1.material.mainTexture = texture1;

  if (texture2 != null) {
    renderer2.material.mainTexture = texture2;
  }
  if (texture3 != null) {
    renderer3.material.mainTexture = texture3;
  }
  if (texture4 != null) {
    renderer4.material.mainTexture = texture4;
  }

}

public void callExample(){
     example(texture1, texture2);
};
```

Comment: `params Texture[] textures` ?

Comment: @tym32167 в моем случае как я понял мне нужно было задать дефолтное значение для параметров вот так: void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2 = null, Texture texture3 = null, Texture texture4 = null){}

Comment: @tym32167 А можно подробнее? Дело в том что у меня сцена в которой есть UI с кнопками и 3d экраны, при нажатии на кнопки на экранах появляются картинки. Сейчас я делаю как в функции сверху, передаю текстуры в функцию, а для этого создал с крипт с огромным количеством пуьбличных переменных, в которые эти текстуры подцепил. Не посоветуете другой вариант, через массив может бть элегантнее решение?

Comment: Оно и так и так будет работать, но ваше решение может быть вам подходит больше, так как там нельзя указать больше 4х параметров.

Comment: Я в юнити не разбираюсь, потому не могу сказать как лучше :)

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое!

Comment: В Вашем случае: 1. изучите основы C#; 2. используйте перегрузку методов (создайте 4 метода с одинаковым названием, но разным кол-вом аргументов)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать дефолтные значения у параметров:
`private void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2 = null, Texture texture3 = null, Texture texture4 = null)`

Кроме этого, можно использовать ключевое слово [params](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):
`private void example(params Texture[] textures)`
Теперь вы можете вызвать метод `example` с произвольным количеством аргументов типа Texture. Все элементы будут помещены в массив `textures`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Следуя примеру с массивом textures, как бы выглядела измененная функция использующая эти текстуры из массива?

Comment: @Rumata просто смотришь сколько в масиве элементов и обрабатываешь их каким-нибудь циклом, например.

Answer (score -1):

В моем случае как я понял мне нужно было задать дефолтное значение для параметров вот так:

```
void example(Texture texture1, Texture texture2 = null, Texture texture3 = null, Texture texture4 = null)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку количество параметров фиксировано, используйте дефолтные значения вместо *params* - кроме первого.

Также проверьте первый для *null*.

Может использоваться локальная функция для упрощения кода.

Ваши *renderers* определены вне *scope* функции, поэтому они должны быть *member variables* так что назовите их, начиная с "_", например: *_renderer1*.

```
    private void SetTexture(Texture texture1, Texture texture2 = null, Texture texture3 = null, Texture texture4 = null)
    {
        if (texture1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(texture1));
            
        void SetTexture(Renderer renderer, Texture texture) =>
            if (texture != null)
                renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
        
        SetTexture(_renderer1, texture1);
        SetTexture(_renderer2, texture2);
        SetTexture(_renderer3, texture3);
        SetTexture(_renderer4, texture4);
    }
```

У вас также может быть *extension method* в вашем рендерере, например:

```
    public static void class RendererExtensions
    {
        public static void SetTexture(this Renderer renderer, Texture texture = null) =>
            if (texture != null)
                renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
```